# How To Unit Test LiveData in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I've got following login method on my ViewModel:

```
public void onLoginClicked(final String userName, final String password) {

            Disposable disposable = userDataManager.login(userName, password)
                    .doOnSubscribe(onSubscribe -> loginLoadingEvent.postValue(true))
                    .doFinally(() -> loginLoadingEvent.postValue(false))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(user -> loginSuccessEvent.call());
}
```

Where loginLoadingEvent and loginSuccessEvents are

```
private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> loginLoadingEvent = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
private final MutableLiveData<Void> loginSuccessEvent = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
```

Where SingleLiveEvent is from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

Now I want to do simple UnitTest, that check if those events were called:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginFragmentViewModelTest {

    @Rule
    public InstantTaskExecutorRule rule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
    private LoginFragmentViewModel loginFragmentViewModel;

    @Mock private Observer<Void> loginSuccessObserver;
    @Mock private Observer<Boolean> loginLoadingObserver;

    public LoginFragmentViewModelTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(__ -> Schedulers.trampoline());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        UserDataManager userDataManager = mock(UserDataManager.class);
        User mockedUser = mock(User.class);

        when(userDataManager.login("testLogin", "testPass"))
                .thenReturn(Single.just(mockedUser));

        loginFragmentViewModel = new LoginFragmentViewModel(userDataManager);

        loginFragmentViewModel.getLoginSuccessEvent().observeForever(loginSuccessObserver);
        loginFragmentViewModel.getLoginLoadingEvent().observeForever(loginLoadingObserver);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin_validEmailAndPassword() {
        loginFragmentViewModel.onLoginClicked("testLogin", "testPass");

        verify(loginLoadingObserver).onChanged(true);
        verify(loginLoadingObserver).onChanged(false);
    }
}
```

I think this unit test should pass pat it returns error in most of the cases (in some strange race condition cases test will pass).

```
loginLoadingObserver.onChanged(true);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at LoginFragmentViewModelTest.testLogin_validEmailAndPassword(LoginFragmentViewModelTest.java:75)
But was 0 times.
```

I think it's because of postValue(), f.e. when I add `Thread.sleep(2000)` test will pass always.
Does `InstantTaskExecutorRule` apply also for postValue?

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: you might want to set `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to trampoline as well

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks you are right, that do the trick

Comment: @Blackbelt you saved my day. thank so much !!!